# Как сравнить два числа

Tags: python, while

Почему-то не сравнивает два числа - `b = 23.0` и полученное с сайта `a =my_float`.

Выдает:

> Цикл окончен,  my_float = 27.0

Ошибок в коде 0. В чем мб проблема?

```
driver.get("https:")
sleep(100)

b = 23.0
convert = driver.find_element("xpath",
                                    "/html/body/div[2]")
match = re.findall(r"(\d+)\s", convert.text)
my_float = float(match[0])
a =my_float

while a < b:
    driver.get("https://google.com")
else:
    print('Цикл окончен,  my_float =',  my_float)
```

Comment: Вы сравниваете `a < b` ~ `my_float < b` ~ `27 < 23`, вот и получаете `False` на первом же вызове

Comment: Для начала расскажи, что этот код должен делать.

Comment: Язык бы тоже было бы неплохо знать. Я python поставил, так как похож на него, но я не уверен.

Comment: Проблема решена. ''Для начала расскажи, что этот код должен делать.'' - я вроде ясно описал проблему - Сравнение двух чисел да и в коде видно while a < b:

Comment: И кроме того, потенциально показанный цикл бесконечный, так как ни одно из значений `a`, `b` не изменяется в нём.

Comment: Число  (a) динамическое - и меняется очень часто. Только вот как действительно его зациклить это вопрос. Т.к. перепробовал уже многое. Работает только def open(): ..... open()Однако почему-то выполняет только открытие сайта driver.get("https:") по кругу. Из кода ниже

Comment: А ну и убрал else

Comment: Тоже самое происходит и с while x<10........x +=1  крутит страницу а код дальше не выполняет

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Все отрабатывает корректно.
Для выполнения инструкций внутри while необходимо, чтобы условие было true.
У вас условие 27<23, что преобразуется в false. Из-за этого инструкции внутри цикла не выполняются ни разу.

Дополнено:

Возможно, вам подойдет не конструкция "while a < b:", а "if a < b:". Т.к. даже, если внутрь цикла вы попадете - программа из него не выйдет без конструкций типа "break"

Полагаю, код, который вам нужен должен выглядеть примерно так:

```
while True:
    driver.get("https:")
    sleep(100)
    b = 23.0
    convert = driver.find_element("xpath",
                                "/html/body/div[2]")
    match = re.findall(r"(\d+)\s", convert.text)
    my_float = float(match[0])
    a = my_float
    if a < b:
        driver.get("https://google.com")
    else:
        print('Цикл окончен,  my_float =',  my_float)
```

Comment: Но число 27 динамическое и я жду когда оно поменяется и станет меньше 23 тогда срабатывает код.

Comment: значит надо чтобы цикл работал пока оно не станет меньше 23

Comment: т.е. я как понимаю нужно делать цикл в цикле? один цикл проверяет число а второй перезагружает цикл и если всё-таки число стало меньше срабатывает к примеру переход на сайт так?

Comment: @fourry да. Можете обернуть код в основной цикл “while true:” Будьте внимательны, чтобы внутри цикла с условием a<b,  эти параметры менялись, а то выйти из этого цикла уже не получится.

Comment: Огромное спасибо. Все работает. Так и думал что convert  требуется внутри цикла т.к. значение бралось всего один раз и при его изменении выдавало число - то что взяло в начале(без его обновления).

Comment: @fourry отлично. Отметьте ответ решением)

Comment: Еще маленький нюанс по поводу загрузки оперативки. Т.к. число печатает мне каждую долю секунды оперативка грузиться на 60%. даже убрав все принты загрузка 56%. Так и должно быть? или возможно как то по-другому решить задачу с кодом для определения числа (a)?

Comment: @fourry с этим не смогу помочь, лучше задайте отдельный вопрос по этой теме, будет интересно посмотреть на решение. Могу посоветовать разве что sleep заменить, вроде не самая уважаемая конструкция.

Comment: извиняюсь но не могли бы вы мне помочь в заключительном моменте: [https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1563641/%d0%9d%d0%b5%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%b8%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%bd%d0%be-%d0%b2%d1%8b%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%bb%d0%bd%d1%8f%d0%b5%d1%82%d1%81%d1%8f-%d1%86%d0%b8%d0%ba%d0%bb)]

Comment: По поводу загрузки - скорей всего больше процессор грузит. но Этот вопрос на потом т.к. поставленную мною задачу я пока до конца не решил.