# Неправильно выполняется цикл

Tags: python

В общем проблема такого рода: требуется, чтобы код после завершения цикла while отработал заново(но лучше бесконечно, пока сам не остановлю). Однако, при таком использовании кода выдает ошибку

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\Users\Fourry\PycharmProjects\Selenium_Piton\Chrom\G2.py", line 33, in <module>
    latest_price = get_started()
```

Сам код:

```
b = 26.0               # постоянная переменная
driver.get("https://") # не важный для кода переход на страницу
sleep(10)              # спим(ждем)
def get_started():     # создаю функцию 
    driver.find_element("xpath", "/html/").click() # клик по ссылке нужный для меня (не обязательно, но он как раз таки срабатывает а дальше нет) 
    convert = driver.find_element("xpath","html/") # считывание строки  
    match = re.findall(r"(\d+)\s", convert.text)  # выборка числа из строки
    return float(match[0]) # выбор числа из скобок и вывод, для себя для проверки.
if get_started() >= b:
    print(f"Текущиее значение: {get_started()}")
    while True:               # Запуск бесконечного цикла
        latest_price = get_started() # Проверка появившегося числа
        if latest_price < b:  # Если a<b ожидаем завершения сценария ниже
            driver.find_element("xpath", "/html/").click() # производим клик         
            print("Все Ок") # Вывод сообщения что все прошло удачно       
            latest_price = get_started() # Повторяем цикл

print("Конец")
```

Изменил код теперь проходит до if - того что после While и выдает ошибку.

```
while True:
    b = 25.0
    convert = driver.find_element("xpath",
                                  "html")
    match = re.findall(r"(\d+)\s", convert.text)
    my_float = float(match[0])
    a = my_float
    if a < b:
        driver.find_element("xpath",
                            "/html").click()
        sleep(3) 
        print('Все ок')

print("Конец")
```

При таком коде он отрабатывает все как надо но один раз.

Comment: **Комментарии были [перемещены в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/151153/discussion-on-question-by-fourry---); пожалуйста, не продолжайте дискуссию здесь.** Прежде чем разместить комментарий ниже этого, пожалуйста, ознакомьтесь с [назначением комментариев](/help/privileges/comment). Комментарии, которые не запрашивают уточнения или не предлагают улучшения, скорее всего должны быть [ответами](/help/how-to-answer), размещены на [meta] или написаны в [chat]. Комментарии, продолжающие дискуссию, могут быть удалены.

Comment: @Amgarak День добрый,  В общем изменил код еще раз, уже мне кажется немного ближе к тому что требуется. Переписал весь вопрос соответственно.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Благодарю всех за помощь!!! С ответом на вопрос я справился!!! Все работает отлично, даже лучше чем предполагал.

### Рабочий код:

```
def get_started():
        
        convert = driver.find_element("xpath",
                                      "html/")
        match = re.findall(r"(\d+)\s", convert.text)
        return float(match[0])

   
    if __name__ == "__main__":
        
        latest_price = get_started()
        print(f"Текущее Число: {latest_price}")

        while True:
            b = 25.0
        
            new_price = get_started()
            
            if new_price < b:
               
                driver.find_element("xpath", "/html/").click()
                print("Прошло")
                sleep(10)
                print('Все ок')
                driver.find_element("xpath",
                                    "/html/").click()
                sleep(5)
                driver.find_element("xpath",
                                    "/html/").click()
```

Comment: Если у кого либо есть желание в помощи либо развитии кода(я его уже немного доделал), пишите. Т.К, и у меня есть вопросы. ( он иногда обрывается)